Unable to render mermaid diagrams using Jekyll spaceship
I'm using the jekyll spaceship plugin for my Jekyll website.
In the Gemfile, I have
gem 'jekyll-spaceship', group: :jekyll_plugins
In my _config.yml, I have
plugins:
  - jekyll-spaceship

Then I ran bundle install, and did jekyll build then jekyll serve.
However, my expected mermaid diagram is not rendered.
Here in my markdown file:
  mermaid!  
    graph TD;
        A-->B;
        A-->C;
        B-->D;
        C-->D;
  (``` enclosing)

I have put this into VS Code's markdown mermaid preview to ensure it indeed can show the diagram in terms of markdown syntax.
The corresponding html generated from the markdown has the part:
<pre><code class="language-mermaid">    graph TD;
        A--&gt;B;
        A--&gt;C;
        B--&gt;D;
        C--&gt;D;
</code></pre>

I have also tried adding to my html layout
<!-- Include the Mermaid library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10.9.1/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Mermaid -->
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});
  });
</script>

but still it does not work.
How can it be properly rendered?
